# Cumulative Cost Calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have a table for received material with unit price and a table with issued material without prices, I made a view to combine the two tables and show the tranasactions made for each material sorted by date, I need to calculate the unit price when the material was issued based on previous transactions, and show the cumulative cost for each material. I tried LAG, SUM OVER, INNER SELECT, but I can't get it right.

Received Material Table (MRV):

| StoreNo | MRVNo | MatCode | TransDate | Qty | UPrice | TransCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | 444 | 122 | 1/1/2023 | 50 | 10 | 500 |
| B1 | 555 | 122 | 1/5/2023 | 30 | 20 | 600 |
| B1 | 556 | 122 | 1/6/2023 | 20 | 10 | 200 |

Issued Material Table (MIV):

| StoreNo | MIVNo | MatCode | TransDate | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | 445 | 122 | 1/2/2023 | 30 |
| B1 | 446 | 122 | 1/2/2023 | 20 |
| B1 | 557 | 122 | 1/9/2023 | 10 |
| B1 | 558 | 122 | 1/10/2023 | 40 |

I created a view that has all transactions together with cumulative balance and a row count that resets after each material (MatTrans):

| RowNo | StoreNo | MatCode | TransDate | TransType | TransNo | Qty | Bal | UPrice | TransCost | CCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B1 | 122 | 1/1/2023 | RCV | 444 | 50 | 50 | 10 | 500 | 500 |
| 2 | B1 | 122 | 1/2/2023 | ISS | 445 | -30 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 500 |
| 3 | B1 | 122 | 1/2/2023 | ISS | 446 | -20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 500 |
| 4 | B1 | 122 | 1/5/2023 | RCV | 555 | 30 | 30 | 20 | 600 | 1100 |
| 5 | B1 | 122 | 1/6/2023 | RCV | 556 | 20 | 50 | 10 | 200 | 1300 |
| 6 | B1 | 122 | 1/9/2023 | ISS | 557 | -10 | 40 | 0 | 0 | 1300 |
| 7 | B1 | 122 | 1/10/2023 | ISS | 558 | -40 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1300 |

I want something to do the below:

| RowNo | StoreNo | MatCode | TransDate | TransType | TransNo | Qty | Bal | UPrice | TransCost | CCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B1 | 122 | 1/1/2023 | RCV | 444 | 50 | 50 | 10 | 500 | 500 |
| 2 | B1 | 122 | 1/2/2023 | ISS | 445 | -30 | 20 | 10 | -300 | 200 |
| 3 | B1 | 122 | 1/2/2023 | ISS | 446 | -20 | 0 | 10 | -200 | 0 |
| 4 | B1 | 122 | 1/5/2023 | RCV | 555 | 30 | 30 | 20 | 600 | 600 |
| 5 | B1 | 122 | 1/6/2023 | RCV | 556 | 20 | 50 | 10 | 200 | 800 |
| 6 | B1 | 122 | 1/9/2023 | ISS | 557 | -10 | 40 | 16 | -160 | 640 |
| 7 | B1 | 122 | 1/10/2023 | ISS | 558 | -40 | 0 | 16 | -640 | 0 |

The price for received items is brought from the received material table.
The price for ISS rows is previous row CCost devided by previous row Bal.
and CCost is the summation of previous transactions.

I tried the below:

```
select MatTrans.RowNo, MatTrans.StoreNo, MatTrans.MatCode, MatTrans.TransDate, MatTrans.TransType, MatTrans.TransNo, MatTrans.Qty, MatTrans.Bal, 
CASE WHEN TransType='RCV' 
THEN UPrice 
ELSE SUM(MatTrans.TransCost) OVER (PARTITION BY MatTrans.StoreNo, MatTrans.MatCode ORDER BY RowNo) / LAG(Bal) OVER (PARTITION BY MatTrans.StoreNo, MatTrans.MatCode ORDER BY RowNo)
END AS UPrice,
CASE WHEN  TransType='RCV' 
THEN 
TransCost
ELSE 
SUM(MatTrans.TransCost) OVER (PARTITION BY MatTrans.StoreNo, MatTrans.MatCode ORDER BY RowNo) / (LAG(Bal) OVER (PARTITION BY MatTrans.StoreNo, MatTrans.MatCode ORDER BY RowNo)) * Qty)
END AS TransCost,
CASE WHEN  TransType='RCV' 
THEN 
LAG(CCost) OVER (PARTITION BY MatTrans.StoreNo, MatTrans.MatCode ORDER BY RowNo) + TransCost
ELSE 
LAG(CCost) OVER (PARTITION BY MatTrans.StoreNo, MatTrans.MatCode ORDER BY RowNo) + (SUM(MatTrans.TransCost) OVER (PARTITION BY MatTrans.StoreNo, MatTrans.MatCode ORDER BY RowNo) / (LAG(Bal) OVER (PARTITION BY MatTrans.StoreNo, MatTrans.MatCode ORDER BY RowNo)) * Qty))
END AS CCost
FROM MatTrans
```

but it's not working because the rows calculations are happening during runtime, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why does UPrice change in last table? Where does 16 come from?

Comment: @cloudsafe the unit price for issued material is calculated based on previous cumulative cost divided by previous balance

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursive CTE to solve this, since as you say, the aggregation changes dynamically:

```sql
;WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, N'B1', 122, N'1/1/2023', N'RCV', 444, 50, 50, 10, 500, 500)
    ,   (2, N'B1', 122, N'1/2/2023', N'ISS', 445, -30, 20, 0, 0, 500)
    ,   (3, N'B1', 122, N'1/2/2023', N'ISS', 446, -20, 0, 0, 0, 500)
    ,   (4, N'B1', 122, N'1/5/2023', N'RCV', 555, 30, 30, 20, 600, 1100)
    ,   (5, N'B1', 122, N'1/6/2023', N'RCV', 556, 20, 50, 10, 200, 1300)
    ,   (6, N'B1', 122, N'1/9/2023', N'ISS', 557, -10, 40, 0, 0, 1300)
    ,   (7, N'B1', 122, N'1/10/2023', N'ISS', 558, -40, 0, 0, 0, 1300)
    ) x (RowNo, StoreNo, MatCode, TransDate, TransType, TransNo, Qty, Bal, UPrice, TransCost, CCost) 
)
, cte2 AS (
    SELECT  RowNo, StoreNo, MatCode, TransDate, TransType, TransNo, Qty, Bal, UPrice
    ,   UPrice * QTY AS TranCost
    ,   UPrice * QTY AS CCost
    FROM    cte c
    WHERE   rowno = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  row.RowNo, row.StoreNo, row.MatCode,row.TransDate, row.TransType, row.TransNo, row.Qty, row.Bal, row.Uprice
    ,   row.QTY * CASE WHEN row.transtype = 'RCV' THEN row.Uprice ELSE prev.CCost / prev.bal END
    ,   row.QTY * CASE WHEN row.transtype = 'RCV' THEN row.Uprice ELSE prev.CCost / prev.bal END + prev.CCost
    FROM    cte2 prev
    INNER JOIN cte row 
        ON  row.rowno = prev.rowno + 1
    )
SELECT  *
FROM    cte2
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

The performance might not be great though, since you're basically doing a row by row loop.

Comment: I tried to apply this on my database but as you said the performance is not idle, it takes 1 minute to process 2000 records, and I have 400,000 records :(

Comment: Try adding index on rowid. Or copy to temp table first and add index there